# "Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/user-desktop.lower-test": How to run mysql server on Xubuntu 13.04 (kubuntu-desktop)

Tags: mysql

I have downloaded and unpacked MySQL 5.6.12 to `/opt/mysql/server-5.6`. I want to use this db instead of pre-installed 5.5 version. But neither version works.

When I want to start a server with `mysqld --console` (pre-installed version) I get this error:

```
user@user-desktop:~$ sudo mysqld --console
[sudo] password for user:
130719 19:26:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/user-desktop.lower-test
130719 19:26:17 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/user-desktop.lower-test
mysqld: Can't change dir to '/var/lib/mysql/' (Errcode: 2)
130719 19:26:17 [ERROR] Aborting

130719 19:26:17 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

There are no any of these dirs in my system:

```
/var/lib/mysql/
/var/lib/mysql/
/var/lib/mysql/
```

How can it be? MySQL is pre-installed but dirs are absent. Should I create them manually? Or do I need to do smth else, run some program, to create them? What mode do I need to set for them?

There is some `mysql_install_db` program in the system. Should I run it to set up MySQL?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that you installed MySQL as root `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. This should usually work.

To carry on from what you have here. You can create the missing directories but make sure they are owned by user\group mysql: `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

If you would like to change MySQL's data directory, do so in MySQL's configuration file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Then you can chose between configuring **apparmor** to allow MySQL to read\execute\modify the new data directory and sub directories **or, at your very own risk,** you can remove **apparmor**. You may need to be `root` to do the following:

```
/etc/init.d/apparmor stop
/etc/init.d/apparmor teardown
update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
apt-get purge apparmor
reboot
```

Then you can run `mysql_install_db`.

But then you will have no users in the database ! To solve this:

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking & #Start MySQL manually with no authentication checks
mysql # Access MySQL, no username\password needed
use mysql;
DELETE FROM user;
INSERT INTO `user` (`Host`, `User`, `Password`, `Select_priv`, `Insert_priv`, `Update_priv`, `Delete_priv`, `Create_priv`, `Drop_priv`, `Reload_priv`, `Shutdown_priv`, `Process_priv`, `File_priv`, `Grant_priv`, `References_priv`, `Index_priv`, `Alter_priv`, `Show_db_priv`, `Super_priv`, `Create_tmp_table_priv`, `Lock_tables_priv`, `Execute_priv`, `Repl_slave_priv`, `Repl_client_priv`, `Create_view_priv`, `Show_view_priv`, `Create_routine_priv`, `Alter_routine_priv`, `Create_user_priv`, `ssl_type`, `ssl_cipher`, `x509_issuer`, `x509_subject`, `max_questions`, `max_updates`, `max_connections`, `max_user_connections`) VALUES('localhost','root',PASSWORD('root'),'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','','','','','0','0','0','0'); #Add root user with passowrd, root
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
killall mysqld;
start mysql
mysql -u root -p
# Enter password, which is: root
```